# How can i know my windows 7 product key?

Tags: windows-7, product-key

I have a Dell inspiron N-4050 laptop. And i am running windows 10 pro on it. I have a product key for it and there was windows 7 genuine with the product key from the manufacturer. But now sticker with the product key on the back faded and no product key is there. I also change the Hard drive long ago. Is there any way i can find my product key for windows-7? Or I can give windows 10 pro product key in exchange with windows 7 pro of ultimate or any. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you looking for a Windows 7 key if you're running Windows 10?

Comment: If Windows 7 came with the machine, then having the product key is pointless. It contravenes the licence to attempt to install windows 7 on a different machine. Also, if you upgraded that machine to Windows 10, you don't have a windows 7 licence any more.

Comment: @Seth Windows 10 for me, has now become a headache. It seriously has made me sick. I am going back to windows 7. I hated it to be honest. It has the worst update and installation policy. I want to uninstall some driver means i want to uninstall, why should it show its generosity to auto install it again, auto update it again.

Comment: @StevenDavison so what can i do Steven Davision? Do you have any idea?

Comment: If the installation of windows 10 was done over the top of a windows 7 one, then it's likely that you'll be able to restore to that point. Have a look in 'Settings' > 'Update and Recovery' > 'Recovery'. I believe that you'll find the option to restore here.

Comment: @StevenDavison nope, I installed it from usb by formatting the C drive.

Comment: You can try doing the same with Windows 7, and at activation, use the microsoft telephone line and see if you can get through it that way, but you'll likely need to speak to a person. Other than that, you can either buy a new retail copy of Windows 7 (be careful of pirate copies), or install a Linux Distribution (I'd suggest Mint or Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, based on the comments, if you don't have the paperwork, there isn't a way to retrieve the product key.

If the machine had been upgraded, it would be possible to revert to Windows 7, then use a program such as Produkey to get the Licence Key from the system.